# Access rights for Azure DevOps Services pipeline

Tags: azure, service, azure-devops

What are the best practices for accesses permission for programmers working in Azure DevOps? I would like the programmers to be able to use it, by for example having the possibility to create branches.

As far as I can understand by reading documents such as 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#git-repository

The only permission needed is a contributor? Is this correct or have I misunderstood the whole thing? The organization I’m working for have for example set the contributor to be a member of :
Build Administrators, Endpoint creators, Release Administrators

Answer (score 1):

Creating users is different thing and assining rights is different thing. Your are looking for something named Policies.

Check for **[Branching policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies-overview?view=azure-devops)** in this case.

**EDIT:**

I was confused with the branching rights, however you can follow the [Repository Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops) and **[Branch permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops)** to find how you can give permissions on your projects to users

Comment: what? how is this related to branching policies?

Comment: @4c74356b41 i confused myself with the branching policies

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to project settings and then to repositories. there you will find list of repositories and each repo can have certain rights assigned to it. some are inherited, some assigned. You can modify those to fit your likings.

this is the url: https://dev.azure.com/org_name/project_name/_settings/repositories

For more details, follow this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you quick answer. Have digged into the documentation and repository permissions. I gave definitely som insight.  My concern is that I want a predefined setting for managing the code repository on a team level, thus would no want to give project permission to the programmers. In my azure devops setup I have only on organization with hundreds of teams.

As I understand it, the permission for the repos are set at the project level.  I would like to minimize the project level access since it gives to wide accesses in other cases and other teams. So my hope was that giving programmers contributor access would give the more or less all needed access for the repos out of the box. Such as:
1. Clone, fetch, contribute to pull requests, and explore the contents of a repository
2. Contribute to a repository, create branches, create tags, manage notes

Do not really understand why more access are needed. But could for example give the security control to the build admin role by granting the access to change permission. In this case the ones with build amdnin could adminitrate the security for its own team repos.

Any thoughs on this? Apologize if I have misunderstood you answer...

Comment: you'd need to create an "overlay" (create a security group for each team and grant permissions) or use inheritance blocking (same idea, but vice versa). either way works